# How to tell students to not ask questions

Tags: students

I have very hectic schedule. I do not get time to read new subjects. I am working as teaching assistant for a subject which is very new to me. Material to teach arrives my email from mentor, just on the night before my presentation day and I prepare in hurry manner.

Students in the class are very active and asks questions which obviously I cannot answer. I feel ashamed.

How can I tell students that I am new to that subject and not to ask questions in acceptable manner.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Do you want your students to ask you no questions at all throughout the entirety of the course? Are the certain types you're open to? What's the format of the class (online, 45 minute lectures, ...)?

Comment: Also, why would you agree to help teach a course if you didn't know anything about it? What's your plan going forward? If you're planning on catching up and need to let your students know, that's one thing, but if you're planning on telling your students you won't be able to help them at all, I don't think there's an IPS solution to that. How you plan on approaching this course affects the answer's you'll get.

Answer (score 11):

> How to tell students that I am new to that subject

This part is simple: "I'm sorry, but I am new to this subject. I may not be able to answer all your questions"

> and not to ask doubts in acceptable manner.

This, on the other hand, is something you should not do. If you cannot teach your students what they ask because your seniors have put you in a difficult position, at least teach them how to find out for themselves, or turn it into a learning activity that you pursue together. Teaching them how to learn effectively is is as important a part of your job as imparting facts. You need to move past the idea that not being able to answer a question is somehow shameful, because it isn't, and you certainly don't want to teach your students that there is anything wrong in asking questions in good faith.